# Using java.awt.Point is being set in cmd line prompt, but I can't seem to intitialize the constructor

Tags: java, point

First I am a java beginner, so please be forgiving if I use the wrong vocab for something.

The problem is I am using 2 classes and I can't seem to get my constructor to keep the values of Point x and y coordinate. I have been trying different ways, but can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Point;
```

public class FindRoute {

```
private static boolean randomRoute = false;

/** Driver for the FindRoute project.
 * 
 * @param args an array of four integers containing [x coordinate of car, y coordinate of car, 
 * x coordinate of destination, ycoordinate of destination] 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    if (args.length<5)
    {
        System.err.println( "Usage java FindRoute id Xstart Ystart Xend Yend [random]");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String carId = args[0];
    int xCar = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int yCar = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    int xDestination = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    int yDestination = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);

    Car car = new Car(new Point(xCar, yCar), carId);

    System.out.println(car);
    car.setDestination(new Point(xDestination, yDestination));
    System.out.println(car);    
    System.out.println("xcar= " + xCar);
    System.out.println("ydest = " + yDestination);

    if (args.length == 6) {
        if (args[5].startsWith("r"))
            car.setRandomRoute(true);


    }
    System.out.println(car);


}
```

Then the constructor and toString

```
public Car (Point car, String carID) {

        this.xCar = xCar;
        this.yCar = yCar;
        this.carID= carID;
public String toString() {
        return "Car [id = " + carID + ", location = [x=" + xCar + ", y=" + yCar + "], destination = [x=" + xDestination + ", y=" + yDestination + "]]";
```

My output will pull the string but sets the car point as 0,0. Please give me tips if this is the incorrect way to ask a question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Car (Point car, String carID) {

        this.xCar = xCar;
        this.yCar = yCar;
        this.carID= carID;
}
```

Your constructor is mistake,you are assigning the same reference to the same reference, you should make in this way

```
public Car (Point car, String carID) {
        this.myPoint = car;
        this.carID= carID;
}
```

OR

```
public Car (Point car, String carID) {
            this.xCar = car.x;
            this.yCar = car.y;
            this.carID= carID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Is that a 'dot' operator that a Point object can use (car.x)? I wouldn't have thought just to use 'x' as it wasn't declared or anything in my program. The same question kind of goes for 'myPoint'. Is this just making a copy of what is passed in to the x and y of that Point? Thank you again so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: with '.' you can enter to methods and properties of your object depends on their accessor modifier level (private,public,protected,default). `myPoint` is a Point reference that references an object , the same as car, so it's a copy of your reference but both referencing to the same object, so if you change car.x = 54 then myPoint will be affected but if you make car = new Point(2,4); myPoint still have the previous val

Comment: You rock! Your explanation just made it 'click' for lack of a better word. Thank you again.

Comment: Just signed up, and it says I require 15 rep. I will as soon as I get it. :)